# Slider on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I created slider on JavaScript(ES2015).
And I just want to be sure that I did my slider good. With all best practise and rules nowadays! thank you for help
Here is my html:

```js
const allSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
 arrows = document.querySelector('.arrows');
let currentSlide = 2;

function reset(dots = document.querySelectorAll('.pagination li')) {
 for ( let i = 0; i < allSlides.length; i++ ) {
  allSlides[i].style.display = 'none';
  dots[i].classList.remove('selected');
 }
 return dots;
}

function createSlider($n) {
 let dots = createSliderPagination(allSlides[$n].parentNode);
 reset(dots);
 allSlides[$n].style.display = 'block';
 dots[$n].classList.add('selected');
}

function createSliderPagination(slider) {
 let pagination = document.createElement('ul');
 pagination.className = "pagination";
 slider.appendChild(pagination);
 allSlides.forEach(function (item, index) {
  let dotWrapper = document.createElement('li'),
   dot = document.createElement('a');
  dotWrapper.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   changeSlide(index);
  });
  dot.setAttribute('href', index);
  dotWrapper.appendChild(dot);
  pagination.appendChild(dotWrapper);
 });
 return pagination.childNodes
}

function changeSlide($n = currentSlide, changer = 0) {
 let dots = reset();
 if ( $n === 0 && changer === -1 ) {
  $n = allSlides.length;
  currentSlide = allSlides.length;
 }
 if ( $n === allSlides.length - 1 && changer === 1 ) {
  $n = -1;
  currentSlide = -1;
 }
 allSlides[$n + changer].style.display = 'block';
 dots[$n + changer].classList.add('selected');
 currentSlide = $n + changer;
}


arrows.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

 if ( e.target.classList.contains("next") ) changeSlide(undefined, 1);

 if ( e.target.classList.contains("prev") ) changeSlide(undefined, -1);

});

createSlider(currentSlide);
```

```css
a,abbr,acronym,address,applet,article,aside,audio,b,big,blockquote,body,canvas,caption,center,cite,code,dd,del,details,dfn,div,dl,dt,em,embed,fieldset,figcaption,figure,footer,form,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,header,hgroup,html,i,iframe,img,ins,kbd,label,legend,li,mark,menu,nav,object,ol,output,p,pre,q,ruby,s,samp,section,small,span,strike,strong,sub,summary,sup,table,tbody,td,tfoot,th,thead,time,tr,tt,u,ul,var,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline}article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section{display:block}body{line-height:1}ol,ul{list-style:none}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:after,blockquote:before,q:after,q:before{content:'';content:none}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}html{background:#f8f8f8}body{font-size:16px;min-width:320px;position:relative;line-height:1.65;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;overflow-x:hidden;opacity:1;background:#f8f8f8}h1{text-align:center}.slider{position:relative;width:640px;height:436px;margin:0 auto;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;border:10px solid #fff;text-align:center;-webkit-border-radius:5px;border-radius:5px;z-index:10;-webkit-box-shadow:0 10px 15px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15),0 5px 20px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);box-shadow:0 10px 15px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15),0 5px 20px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1)}.slider .slide{height:100%;width:auto}.slider .slide img{width:100%;height:100%}.slider .slide figcaption{position:absolute;top:30px;left:30px}.slider .slide figcaption .title{font-size:50px;color:#2ecc71;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:8px}.slider .slide figcaption .author{font-size:18px;font-weight:300;letter-spacing:3px;color:#fff}.arrows{position:absolute;right:30px;bottom:30px;width:100px;overflow:hidden;-webkit-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);box-shadow:0 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.15);z-index:10}.arrows .next,.arrows .prev{float:left;width:50%;height:40px;background-color:#fff;text-align:center;line-height:40px;cursor:pointer;-webkit-transition:.3s color ease;-o-transition:.3s color ease;transition:.3s color ease}.arrows .next:hover,.arrows .prev:hover{color:#2ecc71}.pagination{position:absolute;bottom:-50px;left:50%;right:auto;-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);-ms-transform:translateX(-50%);transform:translateX(-50%)}.pagination li{display:inline-block;float:left;margin:0 5px}.pagination li.selected a{background-color:#2ecc71}.pagination li a{display:block;width:12px;height:12px;-webkit-border-radius:50%;border-radius:50%;border:2px solid #2ecc71;background-color:#fff;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap}
```

```html
<h1>Slider</h1>
<div class="slider">
 <figure class="slide">
  <img src="img/slide1.jpg">
  <figcaption>
   <div class="title">Slide 1</div>
   <div class="author">Diana Bailey</div>
  </figcaption>
 </figure>
 <figure class="slide">
  <img src="img/slide2.jpg">
  <figcaption>
   <div class="title">Slide 2</div>
   <div class="author">Janie Payne</div>
  </figcaption>
 </figure>
 <figure class="slide">
  <img src="img/slide3.jpg">
  <figcaption>
   <div class="title">Slide 3</div>
   <div class="author">Kristina Fitzgerald</div>
  </figcaption>
 </figure>
 <figure class="slide">
  <img src="img/slide4.jpg">
  <figcaption>
   <div class="title">Slide 4</div>
   <div class="author">Beth Garner</div>
  </figcaption>
 </figure>
 <div class="arrows">
  <div class="prev">&#10094;</div>
  <div class="next">&#10095;</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/63eb547q/

Answer (score 1):

I think `%` can save you few lien of code:

```js
function changeSlide($n = currentSlide, changer = 0) {
    let dots = reset();
    currentSlide = ($n + changer) % allSlides.length;
    ~currentSlide || (currentSlide = allSlides.length - 1);

    allSlides[currentSlide].style.display = 'block';
    dots[currentSlide].classList.add('selected');
}
```